# No Connected - No Internet are available Fujitsu P8010 Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have an issue with my internet, for about a month.

My laptop is a Fujitsu Model P8010.

I have already tried to open windows mobility Center...but the "turn wireless on" button is unavailable...

Answer (score 0):

Definately you lack Wireless drivers. It happened with me too. I am 100%sure about this. 
Now you can either download the drivers from your manufacturers website or you can download Driver Pack solution which automatically installs drivers as per your hardware and Windows,But you need to download that pack which is more than 11GB.But the best solution is to download that pack because it does evrything automatically and there is nothing to worry about correct drivers.